# HTML Security (Without CMS)

Tags: html, security

I learned HTML and CSS (Not complete) . Now i can design tiny web site.
For example,i created a website (only html and css without cms) and buy hasting then upload in hasting.
Now my question : what's security means ? , my website is safe ?, all websites That by html and css created don't have security ?, Or my website Security done by hosting company ?.
I will be happy if you help me.
thank you.

Comment: What does _'buy hast thin upload in hast'_ mean?

Comment: I really bad wrote.
it's  "buy hasting then upload in hasting"
thank you

Comment: Sorry, we can't tell you what you mean when you say "secure". What are you trying to guard, and against what kind of threat?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing lots of details about the website and its hosting platform so a strong answer will be difficult. Also, there are some grammar issues with the question. But I can try.

Let's assume that your hosting provider has secured your host against everything but a web attack. So users can't `ssh` into your host, etc... We'll just worry about the difference between your computer with and without the website.

To start off, you probably don't need much website security as it sounds like your site isn't protecting anything valuable. You don't have passwords or credit cards on it. You don't have parts of the site that are restricted to privileged users.

Given those assumptions, what would an insecure site allow an attacker to do? I can think of two things:

1. Your site would allow an attacker to deface your site, making it look different than you wanted.
2. An attacker can use your site to attack another site. For example, if a user of your site also happens to be a user of `mybank.com`, their My Bank account will get hacked.

Most of the attacks that could achieve the above require your site to be a bit more complex than just HTML + CSS. You'd need dynamic page generation to be occurring. So HTML + CSS + JavaScript or HTML + CSS + application server (eg: J2EE or .NET). Being that you don't have either of these, I'm guessing that your site is relatively safe.

I hope this helps. Add more details if you want more specific. Hosting site, web server type, even website URL will allow a better answer.

Comment: Thank you  , I try to create website and send website address for you .